# Use of pronoun in second clause of relative clause

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Which of these sentence is correct in the term of it used below sentence:

> 1. The book that your father brought from India yesterday  your elder brother has brought it in my school today.
> 2. The book that your father brought from India yesterday  your elder brother has brought in my school today.

As the "it" used in one sentence  and other one is without the it. so which one is correct.

Comment: What do you think? Which one seems more natural to you?

Comment: Extreme preposing like this is unnatural. Why do you want to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these sentence constructs feel very natural in English.

Before looking at that, in response to the general thrust of your question, you sometimes don't *need* to use 'it' when what 'it' refers to is clear from the context, but using 'it' is generally preferred (you will be more universally understood).

In English word order is more important than in some other languages where words have different forms according to their grammatical context.  This means that in other languages word order can be used for emphasis and while that is possible in English it can often significantly change the meaning of what you are communicating.

You will need to separate the clauses in the sentence.  There are various opinions on how they should be separated, and how they are separated would then reflect how you complete the rest of the sentence.  I would use a colon after the word 'yesterday', and then use it (with '*in to*').  However I think that separating with a comma and not using 'it' (but still using 'in to') would also be acceptable.

I think that writing this using a verb in the passive voice would be much clearer.

So, In my opinion I think the following three would all be clearly understood:

> 1. The book that your father brought from India yesterday: your elder brother has brought it in to my school today.
> 2. The book that your father brought from India yesterday, your elder brother has brought in to my school today.
> 3. The book that your father brought from India yesterday has been brought in to my school today by your elder borther.

The 'in to' could be replaced by 'to' but 'to' is required (in my opinion at least).

In general, if you are not sure about a sentence construct consider making **it** shorter until you feel clearer.  :o)

Answer (score 0):

The first option, with "**it**", is definitely incorrect. The sentence can't have its subject included twice ("the book that ..." *and* "it").

On the other hand, I can see why someone might be tempted to insert that extra subject (especially in speech) simply because the sentence is so long and complicated, and the thoughts occur in such an inconvenient order.

If it is required that all those concepts be combined into one sentence, I think the best way to phrase the statement would be to re-order it completely:

> Today your elder brother brought to my school the book that your
>   father brought from India yesterday.

But that was not the question. In answer to which is correct, I would have to say neither. The first is clearly wrong, and the second has an inverted word order that isn't used in today's English.

Comment: The second sentence is certainly not idiomatic and needs a comma after yesterday, but it might pass muster in poetic or dramatic circles.